# Open dialog in image click event without postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, image

I need to open a jquery dialog in the img onclick event. But when i click on the image, it makes fullpostback to server which i don't need. I need to open it without postback.

```
<img src='../../images/Cancel1.png' id='img' alt='Image'  onclick='open()'  />
```

[Script]

```
function open() {
        $('#dialog').dialog();

    }
```

Comment: Please add the ASP code where you have the image

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `return false` after you call onclick. So, somewhere on your ASP code:

```
<asp:... OnClientClick="open(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#img').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#dialog').dialog();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as shown below

```
function open() {
        $('#dialog').dialog();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return false when you call OnClientClick